Need a type that expands keys into objects
Ok, so I am upgrading the TypeScript of wj-config (in case the actual case becomes relevant), and one of its functions is to "expand" a key (a string value that is split on the presence of a separator) into an object.  Example:  Key 'a.b.c' expands to object { a: b { c: <value here> } }.
For a single key, I have created the following InflateKey type:
export type InflateKey<TKey extends string, TValue, TSep extends string> = TKey extends `${infer Key}${TSep}${infer Rest}` ?
    {
        [K in Key]: InflateKey<Rest, TValue, TSep>
    } :
    {
        [K in TKey]: TValue;
    };

This type works as expected.  Great!  Now the next task is to accept an object whose keys are like the key described above.  Example:
const dic = {
  'a.b': 1,
  'a.c': 33,
  'h.x': true,
  'z.y': 'Hi'
};

// Now, through the application of a function, the result will look like:

const result = {
  a: {
    b: 1,
    c: 33
  },
  h: {
    x: true
  },
  z: {
    y: 'Hi'
  }
};


I need help typing this return value.
My line of thought:
export type InflateDictionary<TDic extends Record<string, any>> = InflateKey<key1 of TDic,...> & ... & InflateKey<keyN of TDic,...>;

The above, of course, is not valid TypeScript.

You want to intersect a bunch of things? If so, then the approach would be similar to this q's answer, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

Hello, @jcalz.  A pleasure to see you're still spreading the good TS Word, hehe.  Indeed, it seems that you understood and achieved my wanted objective.  As per usual, I don't understand how it works, so I'll be impatiently waiting on your answer to see if I can learn a bit more.

@jcalz, question:  The referenced question has an additional answer about the use of extends for the infer part.  Thoughts on that?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/78704599/13886104

? Feels like a digression. If you want TS to remember that UnionToIntersection<U> produces a type I which is assignable to U, even for generic U, then sure, you can do that, but I don't see that related here, since you're not looking for InflateDictionary<TDic> to extend TDic.

You've already written InflateKey<K, V, "."> (I assume we only care about "." here) and want something that looks like an intersection of InflateKey<K, T[K], "."> for all the properties K in keyof T, right?  If so then we can use the same basic approach as in Transform union type to intersection type.
The idea is that we produce a type where each InflateKey<K, T[K], "."> ends up in a contravariant position (see Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript) such as the parameter of a function. And then we use conditional type inference to infer a single type for that position. Conditional type inference from multiple candidates in contravariant positions produces an intersection (see the documentation in the TypeScript 2.8 release notes).  So here's one way to do it:
export type InflateDictionary<TDic extends Record<string, any>> =
  { [K in string & keyof TDic]:
    (x: InflateKey<K, TDic[K], ".">) => void
  } extends Record<string, (x: infer I) => void> ? I : never;

We make a mapped type over all the string-keyed properties of TDic (string & keyof TDic as opposed to just keyof TDic because InflateKey requires a string key), and put each InflateKey as a function parameter of the property.  Then we infer to Record<string, (x: infer I) => void>, inferring a single I for the whole object. And that I will be the intersection you want, so we return it.

Let's test it out:
const dic = {
  'a.b': 1,
  'a.c': 33,
  'h.x': true,
  'z.y': 'Hi'
};

type Inflated = InflateDictionary<typeof dic>;
/* type Inflated = 
  { a: { b: number; }; } & 
  { a: { c: number; }; } & 
  { h: { x: boolean; }; } & 
  { z: { y: string; };
} */

Looks good. That's the type you wanted.
Playground link to code

Thank you very much for the time you invested in providing such an excellent answer.  I must add that in my particular case an error popped out because it seems that I can end up being unknown.  My final type's final part is now extends Record<string, (x: infer I) => void> ? I extends unknown ? never : I : never;.  Personally, I don't see where the unknown can come from.  If you do see it, it would be nice to read an explanation about it.

It's hard to know without seeing it happen in front of me.

I can easily provide a link to a playground, but it is too long for comments.  If you're willing, how do I give this link to you?

tsplay.dev, maybe?

https://tsplay.dev/m0Dkam

It's not clear to me why you need Record<string, any> to be a constraint everywhere (it's a fairly weak constraint, not much better than unknown) but if you do, you can leverage the extends trick you mentioned earlier like this. Or you could use Extract like this, or any of a number of ways that has little to do with this question as asked (looks like just the next problem you hit after this one).

Right.  All I'm saying is:  I don't see how InflateDictionary can produce unknown.  The constraint in the MergeResult type simply uncovers it.
